# pageSlide: $.pageslide.close(); reloads the website

Tags: jquery

fans,

I'm using the pageSlide plugin with a close button in my menu.

```
$('.close-button').click(function() {
    $.pageslide.close();
});
```

Everytime I'm using the close-button, the site reloads completely... Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

> Description: If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

```
$('.close-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //stop default behavior of anchor tag.
    $.pageslide.close();
});
```

---

**Problem**

your element with class `close-button` is `a` anchor tag with empty `href` which on click  reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Aaaah stupid, just found out :)

```
$('.close-button').click(function() {
    $.pageslide.close();
    return false;
});
```